# Passing JFrame via RMI: isShowing() returns false on client but true on server?

Tags: java, swing, rmi

Can anyone explain why the below code prints this?:
Server: true
Client: false

`isShowing()` is just a getter for a boolean defined in `Component` - shouldn't that serialize properly?

#### RMIInterface.java

```
public interface RMIInterface extends Remote {
    public JFrame getJFrame() throws RemoteException;
}
```

#### RMIClient.java

```
public class RMIClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
        RMIInterface server = (RMIInterface) registry.lookup("myService");
        JFrame frame = server.getJFrame();
        System.out.println("Client: " + frame.isShowing());
    }
}
```

#### RMIServer.java

```
public class RMIServer implements RMIInterface {
    private JFrame frame;

    protected RMIServer() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public JFrame getJFrame() {
        System.out.println("Server: " + frame.isShowing());
        return frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        RMIServer server = new RMIServer();
        RMIInterface stub = (RMIInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);
        registry.bind("myService", stub);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up `isShowing()` and `isVisible()`. `visible` is just a `boolean` property but `showing` implies *actually showing on the screen* and AWT components are never showing when they are just de-serialized. You have to invoke `setVisible(true)` on the `Window` ancestor of the component hierarchy (i.e. the `JFrame`) after de-serialization to make it showing.

---

Just consider [`Component.isShowing()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing%28%29):

> Determines whether this component is showing on screen. This means that the component must be visible, and it must be in a container that is visible and showing.

and [`Window.isShowing()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isShowing%28%29):

> Checks if this Window is showing on screen.

Comment: Is there any way to make sure what I see on the client is an actual reflection on the JFrame on the server? Perhaps passing it by reference (if possible)?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. If you were able to pass a reference it wasn’t **R** MI we are talking about. The “R” stands for __r__ emote, not local. What’s further above me is why you distrust the serialization of a `JFrame`. It will be an equivalent copy. But maybe that’s your problem; you don’t want a copy but think the `JFrame`s on both sides are magically connected. RMI doesn’t work that way. Remote components are the components implementing a `Remote` interface not the parameters or return values.

Comment: Regarding your comment on Window.isShowing(), as far as I can see it's *just* a boolean. Look at the source code: `public boolean isShowing() {
        return visible;
    }` - is that not just returning an instance variable?

Comment: Holger; I understand your confusion, I've not been very good at explaining. Let me try again: I want to control the JFrame in the remote process using RMI. Basically, if I say frame.setVisible(false) on the client, the what I thought happened was that it would forward the call to the actual server object and THEN do the call there. But I guess the problem is that my JFrame isn't a *remote* reference, instead it's copied by-value. So what I actually want is to  make it into a remote reference somehow (like the RMIInterface)?

Comment: That's correct. You have to create your own remote interfaces and implementations for this, probably not based on Swing at all. IBM had a remote AWT in the 1990s but it died, probably for lack of use. I don't recommend you do this. Apart from anything else, the performance will be extremely poor.